# Javascript Regex - Match string shorter than expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

```js
let productIdPattern = /[0-9]{3}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}/ 
let userInput = '123A'
if (userInput.match(productIdPattern)) {
    alert("'123A' is ok, go ahead typing!")
}
```

Given is the above JavaScript pseudo code.

A User is typing a Product-ID. For every keystroke I want to check if the input will match the Product-ID pattern. If not, the keystroke will be ignored. So the input must follow the pattern.

For example:

- Current input is "123", User presses "4" which is **not valid** and will be ignored.
- Current input is "123", User presses "X" which is **valid** and will be appended to the input.

Is there a way to achieve this without making many different or complex patterns for each input length? I need a way to tell the "String.match()" function to ignore the rest of the pattern, if the string is shorter than the pattern.

Comment: Try `/^[0-9]{1,3}(?:[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{0,3})?$/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Wouldn't that match `123X4`, which isn't valid (there apparently needs to be a sequence of three alphabetic characters in between the sequences of digits)?

Comment: @Donut Yes, `^(?:[0-9]{1,2}|[0-9]{3}(?:[A-Z]{1,2}|[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{0,3})?)$` [should work](https://regex101.com/r/6mqN4D/2).

Answer (score 1):

We can create an input filter that only allows entering the desired pattern; everything else is immediately dropped. This is achieved using an in-place replacement pattern:

```html
<input type="text" formControlName="productIdInputC" 
    onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/^([0-9]{3}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{1,3}|[0-9]{3}[A-Z]{1,3}|[0-9]{1,3})?.*$/, '$1')">
```

Though, you should still have server-side validation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern instead:

```
/^(?:\d{1,3}|\d{3}[A-Z]{1,3}|\d{3}[A-Z]{3}\d{1,3})$/
```

You can see a visualization of how this works [here](https://regexper.com/#%5E%28%3F%3A%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%7C%5Cd%7B3%7D%5BA-Z%5D%7B1%2C3%7D%7C%5Cd%7B3%7D%5BA-Z%5D%7B3%7D%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%29%24).